# find the minimum value that is not zero per each group using aggregate function

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
6b9691fa    1   0   2   1   4
6b9691fa    1   1   -1  1   5
6b9691fa    1   2   3   0   4
6b9691fa    2   0   1   5   3
6b9691fa    2   1   0   5   3
6b9691fa    2   2   3   5   3
6b9691fa    3   0   10  1   9
6b9691fa    3   1   10  0   9
6b9691fa    3   2   10  1   9
```

I would like to find the minimum value in the 4th, 5th, and 6th columns per each group of the 2nd column (i.e., three groups that are 1, 2, and 3). The minimum value should not be zero. To do that, I did the following:

```
 aggregate(dataset[,4:6], list(dataset$V2), min)
```

But that returns zero. What can I do in order to avoid zero as a minimum?

Comment: Please share the data in a copy-paste friendly format.

Comment: When minimum  value is zero, are you looking for second minimum?

Comment: @JasonMathews Yes, the second minimum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be this is what you want:

```r
dataset <- read.table(text = '6b9691fa    1   0   2   1   4
6b9691fa    1   1   -1  1   5
6b9691fa    1   2   3   0   4
6b9691fa    2   0   1   5   3
6b9691fa    2   1   0   5   3
6b9691fa    2   2   3   5   3
6b9691fa    3   0   10  1   9
6b9691fa    3   1   10  0   9
6b9691fa    3   2   10  1   9')

aggregate(x = dataset[, 4:6],
          by = list(dataset[, 2]),
          FUN = function(t) min(t[t != 0]))
#>   Group.1 V4 V5 V6
#> 1       1 -1  1  4
#> 2       2  1  5  3
#> 3       3 10  1  9
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

With `data.table`:

```
setDT(dataset)
dataset[, lapply(.SD, function(x) min(x[x != 0])), by = V2, .SDcols = V4:V6]
#    V2 V4 V5 V6
# 1:  1 -1  1  4
# 2:  2  1  5  3
# 3:  3 10  1  9
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `summarise_each` from `dplyr`

```
df <- fread("Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6
6b9691fa    1   0   2   1   4
6b9691fa    1   1   -1  1   5
6b9691fa    1   2   3   0   4
6b9691fa    2   0   1   5   3
6b9691fa    2   1   0   5   3
6b9691fa    2   2   3   5   3
6b9691fa    3   0   10  1   9
6b9691fa    3   1   10  0   9
6b9691fa    3   2   10  1   9")

df %>% group_by(Col2) %>%
  summarise_each(function(x) min(x[x != 0]),Col4:Col6)


# A tibble: 3 x 4
   Col2  Col4  Col5  Col6
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    -1     1     4
2     2     1     5     3
3     3    10     1     9
```

Comment: `summarise_each` is deprecated in favour of `summarise_at`

Comment: Thanks. Weird that `R` didn't even throw any warning message about that